# How to make waiting for the completion of actions, then receive a new message?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, microservices, nestjs

I'm creating microservice by nestjs, transfer throw rabbitmq.
How to make microservice receive messages from queue in turn waiting for complete of the previous one.

- main.ts

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { Transport } from '@nestjs/microservices';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice(AppModule, {
    transport: Transport.RMQ,
    options: {
      urls: [`amqp://localhost:5672`],
      queue: 'rmq_queue',
      queueOptions: { durable: false },
      prefetchCount: 1,
    },
  });

  await app.listenAsync();
}

bootstrap();
```

- app.controller.ts

```
import { Controller, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { EventPattern } from '@nestjs/microservices';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  @EventPattern('hello')
  async handleHello(): Promise<void> {
    Logger.log('-handle-');
    await (new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000)));
    Logger.log('---hello---');
  }
}
```

- client.js

```
const { ClientRMQ } = require('@nestjs/microservices');

(async () => {
  const client = new ClientRMQ({
    urls: ['amqp://localhost:5672'],
    queue: 'rmq_queue',
    queueOptions: { durable: false },
  });

  await client.connect();

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    client.emit('hello', 0).subscribe();
  }
})();
```

https://github.com/heySasha/nest-rmq

Actual output:

```
[Nest] 9560   - 05/14/2019, 1:53 PM   -handle- +2ms
[Nest] 9560   - 05/14/2019, 1:53 PM   -handle- +9ms
[Nest] 9560   - 05/14/2019, 1:53 PM   -handle- +12ms
[Nest] 9560   - 05/14/2019, 1:54 PM   ---hello--- +4967ms
[Nest] 9560   - 05/14/2019, 1:54 PM   ---hello--- +2ms
[Nest] 9560   - 05/14/2019, 1:54 PM   ---hello--- +1ms
```

But i expect:

```
[Nest] 9560   - 05/14/2019, 1:53 PM   -handle- +2ms
[Nest] 9560   - 05/14/2019, 1:54 PM   ---hello--- +5067ms
[Nest] 9560   - 05/14/2019, 1:53 PM   -handle- +2ms
[Nest] 9560   - 05/14/2019, 1:54 PM   ---hello--- +5067ms
[Nest] 9560   - 05/14/2019, 1:53 PM   -handle- +2ms
[Nest] 9560   - 05/14/2019, 1:54 PM   ---hello--- +5067ms
```

Comment: Do you want to achieve a synchronous call to that endpoint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have written custom strategy.

```
import { isString, isUndefined } from '@nestjs/common/utils/shared.utils';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { CustomTransportStrategy, RmqOptions, Server } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import {
    CONNECT_EVENT, DISCONNECT_EVENT, DISCONNECTED_RMQ_MESSAGE, NO_MESSAGE_HANDLER,
    RQM_DEFAULT_IS_GLOBAL_PREFETCH_COUNT,
    RQM_DEFAULT_PREFETCH_COUNT,
    RQM_DEFAULT_QUEUE, RQM_DEFAULT_QUEUE_OPTIONS,
    RQM_DEFAULT_URL,
} from '@nestjs/microservices/constants';

let rqmPackage: any = {};

export class ServerRMQ extends Server implements CustomTransportStrategy {
    private server: any = null;
    private channel: any = null;
    private readonly urls: string[];
    private readonly queue: string;
    private readonly prefetchCount: number;
    private readonly queueOptions: any;
    private readonly isGlobalPrefetchCount: boolean;

    constructor(private readonly options: RmqOptions['options']) {
        super();
        this.urls = this.getOptionsProp(this.options, 'urls') || [RQM_DEFAULT_URL];
        this.queue =
            this.getOptionsProp(this.options, 'queue') || RQM_DEFAULT_QUEUE;
        this.prefetchCount =
            this.getOptionsProp(this.options, 'prefetchCount') ||
            RQM_DEFAULT_PREFETCH_COUNT;
        this.isGlobalPrefetchCount =
            this.getOptionsProp(this.options, 'isGlobalPrefetchCount') ||
            RQM_DEFAULT_IS_GLOBAL_PREFETCH_COUNT;
        this.queueOptions =
            this.getOptionsProp(this.options, 'queueOptions') ||
            RQM_DEFAULT_QUEUE_OPTIONS;

        this.loadPackage('amqplib', ServerRMQ.name, () => require('amqplib'));
        rqmPackage = this.loadPackage(
            'amqp-connection-manager',
            ServerRMQ.name,
            () => require('amqp-connection-manager'),
        );
    }

    public async listen(callback: () => void): Promise<void> {
        await this.start(callback);
    }

    public close(): void {
        if (this.channel) {
            this.channel.close();
        }

        if (this.server) {
            this.server.close();
        }
    }

    public async start(callback?: () => void) {
        this.server = this.createClient();
        this.server.on(CONNECT_EVENT, (_: any) => {
            this.channel = this.server.createChannel({
                json: false,
                setup: (channel: any) => this.setupChannel(channel, callback),
            });
        });
        this.server.on(DISCONNECT_EVENT, (err: any) => {
            this.logger.error(DISCONNECTED_RMQ_MESSAGE);
        });
    }

    public createClient<T = any>(): T {
        const socketOptions = this.getOptionsProp(this.options, 'socketOptions');
        return rqmPackage.connect(this.urls, socketOptions);
    }

    public async setupChannel(channel: any, callback: () => void) {
        await channel.assertQueue(this.queue, this.queueOptions);
        await channel.prefetch(this.prefetchCount, this.isGlobalPrefetchCount);
        channel.consume(
            this.queue,
            (msg: any) => this.handleMessage(msg)
                .then(() => this.channel.ack(msg)) // Ack message after complete
                .catch(err => {
                    // error handling
                    this.logger.error(err);
                    return this.channel.ack(msg);
                }),
            { noAck: false },
        );
        callback();
    }

    public async handleMessage(message: any): Promise<void> {
        const { content, properties } = message;
        const packet = JSON.parse(content.toString());
        const pattern = isString(packet.pattern)
            ? packet.pattern
            : JSON.stringify(packet.pattern);

        if (isUndefined(packet.id)) {
            return this.handleEvent(pattern, packet);
        }

        const handler = this.getHandlerByPattern(pattern);

        if (!handler) {
            const status = 'error';

            return this.sendMessage(
                { status, err: NO_MESSAGE_HANDLER },
                properties.replyTo,
                properties.correlationId,
            );
        }

        const response$ = this.transformToObservable(
            await handler(packet.data),
        ) as Observable<any>;

        const publish = <T>(data: T) =>
            this.sendMessage(data, properties.replyTo, properties.correlationId);

        if (response$) {
            this.send(response$, publish);
        }

    }

    public sendMessage<T = any>(
        message: T,
        replyTo: any,
        correlationId: string,
    ): void {
        const buffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(message));
        this.channel.sendToQueue(replyTo, buffer, { correlationId });
    }
}
```

The core thing changed from the standard [`ServerRMQ`](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/microservices/server/server-rmq.ts) is `setupChannel()` part where we now pass `noAck: false` and acknowledge manually in the *finally* part of the `this.handleMessage(msg)` using `this.channel.ack(msg)`.

Answer (score 5):

What you want to have is usually accomplished with consumer acknowledgments. You can read about them [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html). In short, your consumer (in your case Nest.js microservice), that has prefetch count set to 1, will receive a new message only after it acknowledges a previous one. If you are familiar with AWS SQS, this operation is similar to deleting message from the queue.

Nest.js uses amqplib under the hood for communicating with RabbitMQ. Consumer acknowledgment policy is established during channel [creation](https://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#channel_consume) - you can see there's a `noAck` option. However, the channel is created with `noAck` set to `true` - you can check it [here](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/microservices/server/server-rmq.ts#L82), which means that it's the listener who automatically acknowledges messages when they are passed to your `@EventHandler` method. You can verify that with RabbitMQ management plugin, that provides handy UI and ability to check non acked messages in flight.

I failed to find any useful info about that both in Nest.js sources and docs. But this might give you a hint.

Comment: Thank you! I think, that need to create Custom Transport, https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/custom-transport.

Comment: @AleksandrYatsenko sounds like a solution. I'm gonna be a bit selfish and leave a link here to my npm package, that can actually be very useful in your case. If you find that it fits your needs, enjoy: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nabbitmq

Answer (score 2):

You should add  `noAck: false` to main.ts.

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { Transport } from '@nestjs/microservices';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice(AppModule, {
    transport: Transport.RMQ,
    options: {
      urls: [`amqp://localhost:5672`],
      queue: 'rmq_queue',
      queueOptions: { durable: false },
      noAck: false,
      prefetchCount: 1,
    },
  });

  await app.listenAsync();
}

bootstrap();
```

Additionally, you have to add `context` to the controller and make the `ack`nowledgment.

```
import { Controller, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import {  Ctx, EventPattern, RmqContext } from '@nestjs/microservices';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  @EventPattern('hello')
  async handleHello(@Ctx() context: RmqContext): Promise<void> {
    Logger.log('-handle-');
    await (new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000)));
    Logger.log('---hello---');

    const channel = context.getChannelRef();
    const originalMsg = context.getMessage();
    channel.ack(originalMsg);
  }
}
```

Comment: i think channel.ack should be before  setimeout or any other action ,  so rabbitMQ no that someone handling this message